# Table Name After Subquery in a JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to oracle sub-queries, I'm faced with this sub-query:

```
select  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_RCE_ID, CUSTOMER.COMM_REGNUM_CUST,CUSTOMER.GROUP_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CORPORATE_NAME, 
Replace(CUSTOMER.ADDRESS_COMPANY, '|', ', ') as ADDRESS_COMPANY, CUSTOMER.COUNTRY_CODE, CUSTOMER.POST_CODE, CUSTOMER.CITY, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE1,
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE2, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE3, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE4, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ATTRIBUTE5, 
CUSTOMER.CREATED_DATE, CUSTOMER.CREATED_BY,CUSTOMER.UPDATED_DATE, CUSTOMER.UPDATED_BY, CUSTOMER.TENANT_ID, 
CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT, CUSTOMER.VAT_INTRA, CUSTOMER.VAT_SETTLEMENT,CUSTOMER.IS_HEADQUARTERS, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_SAP_ID, 
CUSTOMER.ADDRESSGUID, CUSTOMER.SIREN_CORP, CUSTOMER.COMMERCIAL_SEGMENT, CUSTOMER.CODE_NAF, CUSTOMER.JUR_STATUS_COMP, 
CUSTOMER.SHARE_CAP_AMT,CUSTOMER.IS_ACTIVE_RCE, CUSTOMER.REGISTRATION_PLACE,STATUS.STATUS_NAME , 
CUSTOMER.RCE_ETAB_ID, REPLACE (CUSTOMER.COMM_REGNUM_CUST,' ','') AS SIRET  from CUSTOMER

join CUSTOMER_STATUS on CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID = (
select * from (select CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID from CUSTOMER_STATUS 
where CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_ID order by CUSTOMER_STATUS.UPDATED_DATE desc)  CUSTOMER_STATUS where rownum = 1)
```

I don't understand this part:

```
select * from (select CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID from CUSTOMER_STATUS 
where CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_ID order by CUSTOMER_STATUS.UPDATED_DATE desc)  CUSTOMER_STATUS where rownum = 1
```

How can we put CUSTOMER_STATUS after the sub-query? and why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Customer_Status is a table alias.  every inline view should contain an alias so that if columns in the query are named the same as columns in other tables, the engine can differentiate the columns.  In this case it's the same name as a table already in the join which I would say is bad from to use an alias named the same as a table, but since it's at a different level in a subquery the two don't conflict.

Comment: It's a little confusing in this case since the table alias is never actually used. It could be removed and the query would work fine.

Comment: I am a bit confused that customer_Status doesn't seem to have an alias as status is revered to in the select Status.status_name  but maybe there's a table called status somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This is an... interesting join. The `Customer_Status` after the close parentheses is a table alias. You could just have easily have replaced it with `sadfkjhasldkgjh` and it would work just fine. It tells the program that you have selected data in a table structure and you will hereon refer to it by this name (alias). It makes it easier for you to use.

In this case, the entire statement is a bit convoluted. You apparently already have a table named CUSTOMER_STATUS and you are aliasing a subquery as the same name. Oracle will let you do this, but the results quickly become confusing to keep track of. Best practice, do not alias a subquery as the same name as an existing table.